# xpath to let the nearest ancestor's attribute value decides if it's in or not

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm looking for the right xpath expression to select all nodes whose nearest ancestor have the proper attribute value, and not to select those whose nearest ancestor have an explicit 'don't select' attribute value.
Visually explained: for each branch, follow its path to the root, and the first time a certain attribute is encountered should decide if it is in the selection or not.

```
<xyz select="yes">
    <blabla>this one's in</blabla>
    <qwerty select="no">this one's out
        <foobar>out please!</foobar>
        <gettingoutofnames select="yes">in again!</gettingoutofnames>
    </qwerty>
</xyz>
```

Example can occur anywhere in the XML structure.

Names of elements can be anything. 'select="yes"' and 'select="no"' can follow in any order, but the deepest one is decisive its descendants.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
//*[@select="yes"]//ancestor::*[not(@select="no")]
```

but that doesn't catch it all. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
//*[ancestor::*[@select][1]/@select='yes']
```

To break it down: `ancestor::*[@select][1]` is the nearest ancestor with a `select` attribute. So we choose only those nodes for which the nearest ancestor with a `select` attribute has this attribute set to `'yes'`. You have to replace `ancestor` with `ancestor-or-self` if you also want to include the nodes the have a `select="yes"` attribute (`xyz` and `gettingoutofnames` in your example).

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Much respect! At the time of writing I needed a quick solution for my problem, so finally I settled with a workaround. It was about the filtering of strings that required translation. But as this translation is still running, I can use your soluction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For selecting a value

```
cat //*[contains(@select,'yes')]
```

For selecting the negate results

```
cat //*[not(contains(@select,'yes'))]
```

Hope you'll figure out the catch for your problem